# Start X (on a Mac) with 'nomodeset' kernel option activated

Tags: linux, boot, mac, arch-linux, xorg

I have a Mac Mini (late 2014).
I'd like to use linux.
I used to install linux many times in the last years and I never get a problem.
Now, I don't know why, no live-cd of any distro boots up.
My monitor goes to sleep (with every distribution) during the boot. 
Exactly when the kernel activates the mode settings, I suppose.
So, i **have** to boot with the 'nomodeset' option.

Now, the problem is that I don't understand how to start X, having the 'nomodeset' option activated.

I get errors like:
- module fbcon not found.
- No screen found
- The number of screens does not match the number of physical devices.

I tried various solutions and searched the net a lot, but nothing works.

X -configure gives me the "module fbcon not found" error.

I'm using arch.

I'd like or to find a solution to start X with 'nomodeset', or find a way to boot my mac without the 'nomodeset', as I did many times in the past.

Comment: Are using default Intel graphics not any eGPU?  You'll can't start x with `nomodeset` (or `vga=`) as it needs kernel mode setting.  I'd imagine (but don't know) that 2014 Mac Mini would be similar to 2014 MBP with only integrated graphics so FWIW on my mid 2014 MBP (with Intel graphics) I use the following kernel parameters for Arch `rw acpi_mask_gpe=0x06 acpi_mask_gpe=0x17 acpi_osi=Darwin quiet loglevel=3 udev.log_priority=3 i915.fastboot=1 splash`.  The [i915](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics) is the only graphics related option and it worked without.

Comment: I tried Fedora, which I'm actually using, and it runs seamlessly with 'nomodeset' option. I'll try your solution as soon as i can. thx

Comment: It suggests in one of the comments on [Linux on MacBook](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7) to install Arch *"You need both `nomodeset` and `i915.modeset=0`. I was able to install Arch with the same ISO release using those 2 params"* but after fully upgrading to latest kernel (`pacman -Syu`) it then works.

Comment: I tried. That doesn't work. Being the installation of arch textual, I could install it. But after install, i don't know how to make X work.